# Erro de certificado ao enviar um e-mail

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer, smtp

Olá, ontem ao enviar um e-mail pelo meu site e de meu cliente criado pelo wordpress, deparei com um erro ao enviar o e-mail:

```
Warning:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`*.locaweb.com.br' did not match expected CN=`smtp.toldosmaranata.com.br' in /home/storage/2/f3/41/toldosmaranata/public_html/wp-includes/class-smtp.php on line 367
```

Fiz algumas pesquisas mas não consegui identificar como resolver esse problema que consta na classe do smtp na linha 367 que irei inserir aqui também para facilitar:

```html
365        if (!stream_socket_enable_crypto(
366            $this->smtp_conn,
367            true,
368            $crypto_method
369        )) {
370            return false;
371        }
372        return true;
373    }
```

Agradeço desde já quem disponibilizar a ajudar, grato!

Comment: É a mesma questão desse link?
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371910/phpmailer-generates-php-warning-stream-socket-enable-crypto-peer-certificate

Comment: Verificando o que informou até consegui entender a respeito do código disponibilizado para colocar dentro do arquivo class-smtp.. mas não sei onde posso colocar lá dentro. Sabe me dizer?

Comment: Na verdade não é no arquivo class.smtp.php, mas sim aonde você instancia a classe PHPMailer, exemplo: $mail = new phpmailer(); $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);

Comment: Certo mas nesse caso, eu utilizo o plugin contact form 7 do wordpress. O erro está vindo do arquivo class-smtp.php e eu não instancioa classe phpmailer em outro lugar.. o que eu teria que fazer?

Comment: Favor, realize um backup do arquivo class.phpmailer.php, e depois altere na linha 275 de `public $SMTPOptions = array()` **para** `public $SMTPOptions = array('ssl'=>
                                  array('verify_peer'=>false, 
                                        'verify_peer_name' => false, 
                                        'allow_self_signed' => true ) 
                               );`

Comment: OPA! Sensacional, o erro foi corrigido e o e-mail está sendo enviado! muito obrigado Everson.

Comment: Embora a solução do @Everson funcione, lembre-se que fazer isto irá desligar a verificação dos cerificados que em geral é totalmente inseguro.

Answer (score 1):

No arquivo class.phpmailer.php na linha 275 troque de:

```
public $SMTPOptions = array();
```

para public

```
$SMTPOptions = array('ssl'=> array('verify_peer'=>false,
                                   'verify_peer_name' => false, 
                                   'allow_self_signed' => true ) );
```

isso irá desativar a verificação do certificado ssl. Apenas faça isso se você tem certeza que o servidor no qual você está enviando seus e-mails são seguros.